# Why should i care about independent triangular arrays?

Tags: random-variable, independence, central-limit-theorem

In Advanced probability class we were building up to proofs of the central limit theorem. We started by stating the theorem of the [Classic CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT), then we introduced the independent triangular array and proved what we called the Lindeberg CLT for these arrays. Then we used this more general CLT to prove the Lyapunov CLT and the classic CLT with the array being of iid random variables. This is all well and good, the central limit theorem is true, but i cant avoid feeling like the Lindeberg CLT of independent triangular arrays is a much more general result than the usual CLT for iid variables. This leads to my (clickbaity) question, what can i do with these independent triangular arrays? This seems to be related to more general situations than sequences of random variables, since the different rows in the array does not need to be related it seems. What are the practical or theoretical applications for this? What made me most curious is how little information i could find online about these arrays, mostly only references to the proof of Lindeberg CLT (just figuring out that it was called array and not schema in english was complicated enough).

For completeness a definition: An independent triangular array is a family $\{\mathsf{X}_{nk}: n \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq k \leq n\} $
of random variables such that $\mathsf{X}_{n1},\dotsc, \mathsf{X}_{nn}$ is independent $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Addendum 10th of June: I have found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373701/triangular-arrays-in-law-of-rare-events-theorem) on the mathematics stackexchange that shows an application where the rows are Bernoulli distributed and when the probability parameter goes to 0 as the row number increases the sum of a row approaches a Poisson distribution. This is an interesting application of the triangular array, although it is not a CLT result.

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a new estimator for a classical linear regression problem, let's call it estimator A. I want to show that estimator A is good. I ran some simulations and realize that estimator potentially works well even when a few outliers (but not too many) are present in the dataset.

I then imagine a world where the leverage of the data $X_i(X'X)^{-1}X_i'$ and the variance of the error term $Var(\epsilon_i)$ correlate to generate a higher chance of outlier occurring. For example, when $X_i(X'X)^{-1}X_i'$ is large, then observation i is far from all the other observations, at the same time, if we allow positive correlation between $X_i(X'X)^{-1}X_i'$ and $Var(\epsilon_i)$, then the same observation is likely to have a large error term, so you can imagine an observation that is far away from all the other observations and likely to deviate from the true regression line. The positive correlation between $X_i(X'X)^{-1}X_i'$ and $Var(\epsilon_i)$ gives rise to a higher chance of outlier occurring. Now, how can I write this down as a data generating process? Imagine the following.

Most of the time, $(X,\epsilon)$ are drawn from a bivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Omega$, imagine that $\Omega$ is a diagonal matrix, so $X_i$ is independent from $\epsilon_i$. With very small probability $\frac{1}{N}$, both the leverage and variance are drawn from a bivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance matrix $N^{q}\Omega$ where $0<q<0.5$. This data generating process ensures that I can expect exactly one outliers no matter what the sample size N is and the number of outliers won't explode as the sample size increases. Also, the unconditional variance of $\epsilon_i$ does not explode as the sample size increases. These properties are desirable for my theoretical work later on.

Now, I want to prove that after some normalization, estimator A converges in distribution to a normal distribution. Lindeberg CLT is useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is power comparisons for tests. Suppose you are testing for mean non-zero vs zero.  If your alternative distribution is the same for all $n$, the power will go to 1 in an uninteresting way.  You might instead want to test $\mu=0$ vs $\mu=\delta/\sqrt{n}$ for some fixed $\delta$. You need a triangular array because the distributions for different $n$ are different at least in their means.